# How to add a different prefix to every line in a grep output?

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I currently have this code:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "MHz" | cut -d ':' -f2 | sed 's/.*/Core NUM&Mhz/'
```

Which outputs the following (for 8 cores):

```
Core NUM 1941.054Mhz
Core NUM 1949.820Mhz
Core NUM 2022.734Mhz
Core NUM 1877.171Mhz
Core NUM 1938.265Mhz
Core NUM 1945.703Mhz
Core NUM 1845.562Mhz
Core NUM 1781.546Mhz
```

What I want to do is replace "Core NUM" with actual numbers (e.g. Core 0, Core 1, Core 2, Core 3...) I would prefer a solution that can be done on one line with the rest of this command, but since I am in the end working from a bash script, I don't mind a multi-line/scripted solution either. The biggest problem I guess is that grep is one command outputting many lines, and I don't know if there's a way to target these lines one by one in something like a for or while loop.

So, how can I do this?

Comment: You can probably replace the `grep`, `cut` and `sed` with `awk` and get `awk` to print the line numbers as well - someone will be along soon with an `awk` solution, I'm sure.

Comment: @EightBitTony you called it!

Comment: yeh, it's not a race, but @cuonglm beat me by about 12 seconds.  I was too busy mis-typing `/proc/cpuinfo` as `/proc/procinfo` and wondering why it wasn't there.

Comment: You do know you can use `cpupower` for that, don't you ? e.g. `cpupower -c all frequency-info -fm` or, to format it per your question `cpupower -c all frequency-info -fm | paste -d' ' - - | cut -c11-` (assuming _en_US_ locale)

Comment: @don_crissti I had no idea about cpupower, and it is irrelevant. I wanted to do this with a stock linux installation (without extra software, which cpupower as far as i'm concerned is) hell, cpupower doesn't even seem to exist in my distro's package repositories.

Comment: @don_crissti fedora 23 (with cinnamon) atm.

Comment: [fedora cpupower](http://eng-mah.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-install-cpupower-package-on.html) - keep in mind there's no such thing as "stock linux installation"

Comment: @don_crissti I know that, what I mean is the most basic, with the basic command line tools that are standard for linux and ship with practically every linux distribution (like grep and ls and cat and awk and sed and other basic stuff most distros will come with ready right out of the box)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let `awk` do it all for you:

```
</proc/cpuinfo awk -F : '/MHz/{printf "Core %d%sMhz\n", n++, $2}'
```

Comment: Great, out of the two answers provided, I think this one is cooler because it's all one command. I'll mark it as an answer if you can show me how to append "MHz" at the end like the other one did :)

Answer (score 3):

`cat /proc/cpuinfo | awk '/MHz/ {print "Core", i++, $NF "Mhz"}'` gives,

```
Core 0 800.000Mhz
Core 1 800.000Mhz
```

Answer (score 3):

I did a slightly different awk version, but once you are familiar with awk, it will stand out as the natural solution for this. I used the following:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | awk -F : '/^processor/ { x = $2 } /^cpu MHz/ { print "CPU" x ":" $2 " MHz" }'
```

which uses a slightly different approach of saving off the value of the 'processor' field and then recalling it when the cpu MHz field is encountered. You can do slightly more general things this way, provided you know which of the fields you are interested in occurs last. In this case, we know the 'cpu MHz' comes after the 'processor' field, so we know that when 'cpu MHz' is encountered, the value stored in the variable x will be correct.

Output looks like:

```
CPU 0: 887.597 MHz
CPU 1: 818.359 MHz
CPU 2: 887.597 MHz
CPU 3: 803.222 MHz
```